# Is generics the solution to this class design?

Tags: c#, generics

I've got an enum with possible values:

```
    public enum Language
    {
        English = 1,
        French = 2,
        German = 3
    }
```

Now i want my class to be dynamic in the sense that it can cater for multiple values based on the enum list.  So if the enum list grew i can capture all possible values.

Here's how my initial design looks:

```
    public class Locale
    {
        public string EnglishValue { get; set; }
        public string FrenchValue { get; set; }
        public string GermanValue { get; set; }
    }
```

But i want something that doesnt need to recompile if the enum list (or any list) grows:  Is it possible to express something like:

```
    public class Locale
    {
        public string StringValue<T> Where T : Language
    }
```

I am open to any suggestions or design patterns that can nicely deal with this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a Dictionary.

```
public class Locale : Dictionary<Language, string>
{
}
```

Whatever you do, if you change the enum, you have to recompile, but what you probably mean is "maintain" the Locale class.

Answer (score 0):

What you're proposing won't work unfortunately. This would be a better design IMHO:

```
public class Locale
{
    public string GetStringValue(Language language)
    {
        // return value as appropriate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic parameters are type parameters, not value parameters, and enum members (at least in C#) are distinct values, not types. The enum (in this case, Language) is indeed a type, but not its members.

Also, the generic class will know that it has a type parameter that is inherited from Language, but since enums are not inheritable in C#, this, and the generic type parameter constraint (the "where T:Langauge" thing) together pretty much mean that the generic type parameter will always be "Language" in all cases so there's no point having a generic class in this case. If I were you, I would do this:

```
public class Locale
{
    public string GetStringValue(Language language)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better for Language to be a class and incapsulate some of the language-specific processing just as System.Globalization.CultureInfo does?

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the other answers you could of course use a Dictionary for the Language list, then populate it from either a local config or database at runtime providing you with extensibility without the need for recompilation.